# Knockout Mapping - Don't want to create object but need to serialize it

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Because I need to access the month, day and year on my page, I have a viewmodel with a compound object, SplitDate.

```
var SplitDate = function(date) {
       var _date = ko.observable(); // the backing field

       this.date = ko.computed({ read: _date, write: setDate });
       this.year = ko.computed({ read: makeGetter('year'), write: makeSetter('year') });
       this.month = ko.computed({ read: getMonth, write: setMonth });
       this.day = ko.computed({ read: makeGetter('date'), write: makeSetter('date') 

       // not showing setters/getters, etc.
       ....
    });
}
```

On my view model, I use this object as follows;

```
self.trainingEndDate = ko.observable(new SplitDate());
```

The problem I'm having is that I need to be able to map new data from an ajax call multiple times for the same page.  I tried allowing Knockout Mapping to create a new SplitDate each time, but that didn't work.  Apparently, the SplitDate that was being dropped and replace was the one that was bound to the page.

So I created a mapping that would ignore the viewmodel proerties that were SplitDates, and for those I just update the date of the existing control.

That worked fine until I needed to unwrap the model and post it using an ajax call. Knockout Mapping sets a flag on the ignore properties, so these aren't being included in the unmapped object.  I'm using a different mapping options that does not "ignore" them and I also tried adding them in using the "include" option but that didn't work.

Why doesn't an explicit "include" supercede an implicit "ignore"?  Should I not be ignoring these objects on the mapping? is there an option I can use to call the date's setter instead of ignoring them?

Getting ahead of myself, but is there something I need to include in the SplitDate to insure it is serialized correctly after I get mapping to actually include it?

Comment: Could you include the code that actually does the mapping / serialization / deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

If you attach members directly to an observable they will be ignored by the mapping. Perhaps the following approach would work better for your needs?

```
var CreateSplitDate = function(date) {
     var _date = ko.observable(); // the backing field

     _date.date = ko.computed({ read: _date, write: setDate });
     _date.year = ko.computed({ read: makeGetter('year'), write: makeSetter('year') });
     _date.month = ko.computed({ read: getMonth, write: setMonth });
     _date.day = ko.computed({ read: makeGetter('date'), write: makeSetter('date') 

     // not showing setters/getters, etc.
     ....

     return _date;
};
```

Then just use:

```
self.trainingEndDate = ko.observable(CreateSplitDate());
```

This will allow you to treat the computed observables pretty much the same as you would using your existing approach. However when you call `ko.mapping.toJS` the members you attached to `trainingEndDate` will be ignored.

Here's a simple example of this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/c46gknfj/

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, while i liked your code better then what I had, it really didn't help with the knockout mapping. If I ignored the properties when mapping, including them when unmapping still didn't work.  And if I DIDN'T ignore them, the mapper was still dropping the object and creating a new one.  It might be something I did wrong in applying your code, but I'm time crunched and can't play with it any longer.  I wound up ignoring the properties on the mapping and then hand-coding them when  unmapping.

Comment: @SteveWash - Would you mind posting a jsfiddle example of what you did?

Comment: I'll try to get that but incredibly crunched. Tech lead quit and I'm the defacto replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar troubles trying to replace an object instance with a new one. My guess is that indeed KO's bindings are lost when this is done. However, from your scenario it seems to me that the assignment consists of:

> Decomposing a date entity into days, months and years without polluting the main viewmodel with these separate entities when sent to the server.

The most logical solution which comes to mind then (and which processes the data **outside** of your VM instead of as a **child property**) is a **component** (which will avoid the mapping trouble altogether). You pass a single property as data, and the component processes and visualizes it in its own, non-mapped viewModel. Eg, let's say the only data you retrieve and store is a string in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`. This is your very minimal VM:

```
var jsonData = '09/10/2015';
var app = {date: ko.observable(jsonData)};
ko.applyBindings(app);
```

Now your `splitDate` object can be used as a VM for the `datepicker` (or viewer) component model. I don't know what's behind your getters and setters, but I made a little [test case here](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/zL4mf00e/1/), using writable computed's with some very basic validation.